# Vuejs2 set timeout fails to execute the function after the set seconds

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

AM trying to execute a function after 1 second using setTimeout but it fails to work

so i have

```
mounted(){
   this.getTime();
}

methods:{
 getTime(){

    setTimeout(()=>{
     console.log("test..");
    },1000)
   }
}
```

THe above only logs once

Ihave tried changing the arrow function in set timout to

```
setTimeout(function(){
  console.log("test")
 }, 1000);
```

But even so it fails

Where am i going wrong as i expect more than one print of test to the console

I prefer using the mounted hook as this function will perform other operations with this keyword which becomes available after mount

Comment: *i expect more than one print of test to the console* , there is just one log call that will be only executed once?!

Answer (score 1):

Use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) instead of [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout).

`setInterval` will repeat until you tell it to stop, whereas `setTimeout` will only run once (unless it is canceled before it gets ran).

```
mounted(){
   this.getTime();
},
methods:{
 getTime(){
    setInterval(()=>{
     console.log("test..");
    }, 1000)
   }
}
```

Your other option is to call `this.getTime()` again at the end of your timeout like this:

```
mounted(){
   this.getTime();
},
methods:{
 getTime(){
    setTimeout(()=>{
     console.log("test..");
     this.getTime();
    }, 1000)
   }
}
```